# Use NSDictionary or create a class with properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, attributes, nsdictionary

I am a beginner in cocoa programming. In my mac os app, I am saving .webarchive files, and I also need to save some app-only data - (like tags, etc) associated with that webarchive. Should I use NSDictionary for these properties or create a class with @properties? What are the advantages of saving attributes in NSDictionary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class properties vs NSArray / NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743840/class-properties-vs-nsarray-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the reason for creating a class/object is when you expect it to have some sort of behaviour. So, if you're likely to repeatedly perform the same manipulations on the data you are saving, then it's probably worth defining a class. If you simply need to save the data and access it later, then an NSDictionary sounds like a more sensible choice.

Comment: Would it be better then to save object properties just in case your application expands, and then there's a need to implement some sort of behavior?

Comment: Personally I think not. If your design is clean then it will not be hard to implement a class with properties at a later date. Be agile! :)